# Регистрация на сайте, не обновляется БД, Ошибок не выдает

Tags: php, база-данных

Сделал простую регистрацию, как результат ошибок не выдает но БД не обновляет! 
Вот код:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "my_bd");

if (!$connect) {
    mysql_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['register'])) { 
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
    $pswd_again = $_POST['pswd_again'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_surname = $_POST['user_surname'];
    $user_age = $_POST['user_age'];
    $user_origin = $_POST['user_origin'];
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO 'users' SET 'login'='$login','password'='$pswd','name'='$user_name','surname'='$user_surname','age'=$'user_age','origin'=$user_origin'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'YEAH!';
}

mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Простор для sql-инъекций. Имена таблиц и полей должны быть не в одинарных кавычках, а в апострофах.

Comment: Интересно почему `mysqli`, но при этом `mysql_error()`

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($connect , "INSERT INTO `users` SET `login`=`$login`,`password`=`$pswd`,`name`=`$user_name`,`surname`=`$user_surname`,`age`=$`user_age`,`origin`=$user_origin`");

Comment: Так тоже ничего не изменилось. Там апострофы стоят теперь.

Comment: Соединение то вообще устанавливается? 
if (!$connect) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO users (login, password, name, surname, age, origin) VALUES ('$login','$pswd','$user_name','$user_surname','$user_age','$user_origin')");
```

Comment: Заработало. Не пойму у меня так было первый раз, но не работало и я сделал через SET.В чём ошибка, тут скобки стоят или апострофы?

Comment: Может я пробелы не ставил раньше здесь: users (login, password, name, surname, age, origin). Выглядело так: users (login,password,name,surname,age,origin) или это не существенно?

Comment: @user225682 в строке `INSERT INTO 'users'` **users** нужно либо заключать в **косые** кавычки либо не заключать в кавычки вообще.

Comment: Да, @Alex верно сказал. Имя таблицы, как и имена полей таблицы пишутся как есть, либо оборачиваются в косые кавычки (апостроф, вроде, называется). Вообще, почитайте мануалы, там примеры есть и про синтаксис запросов рассказывается. И лично мне привычней инпуты делать таким синтаксисом, чем через set. Хотя, через set, возможно, наглядней, т.к. сразу видно, в какое поле что пишется.